# Making a batch request with Google API and cURL - keep getting 400 Bad Request - here is my code:

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

Something is wrong. I keep getting a 400 Bad Request but can't seem to get any other error messages. Here is the code:

```
$locations = array("LAX", "LGW");
$dateOut = '2015-04-25';
$dateIn = '2015-04-29';
$passengers = 1;
$destinations = array("NYC","LAX","CHI","WAS","LAS","SFO","MIA","BOS","DEN","AUS");

$apiQueries = array();
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach ($locations as $origin) {
        $data = array("request" => array(
            "passengers" => array(
            "adultCount" => $passengers
        ),
        "slice" => array(
            array(
                "origin" => $origin,
                "destination" => $destination,
                "date" => $dateOut
            ),
            array(
                "origin" => $destination,
                "destination" => $origin,
                "date" => $dateIn
            )
        ),
        "solutions" => "10"
        ));

        $apiQueries[] = json_encode($data);
    }
}

$batch = '';
$boundary = '--batch_xyzabc';
$i = 0;
foreach ($apiQueries as $data) {
    $batch .= "\n" . $boundary . "\nContent-Type: application/http\n\nGET /qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=my-unique-key" . " \n" . $data . "\n";
    $i ++ ;
    if ($i > 48){
        // we need to split the batch by packs of <50. Close this one and create the next one
        $batch .= "\n" . $boundary . "\n";
        $batches[] = $batch;
        $batch = '' ;
        $i=0;
    }
}

// close the current batch pack
if ($i > 0) $batches[] = $batch . "\n" . $boundary . "\n";

for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($batches) ; $i++) {
    $session = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/batch');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.googleapis.com', 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=' . $boundary, 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $batches[$i])));
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $batches[$i]);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $resp = curl_exec($session);


    echo $resp;exit; // Shows 400 Bad Request message


    $api_response_info = curl_getinfo($session);
    $pack_of_answers = substr($resp, $api_response_info['header_size']);
    curl_close($session);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to call Google APIs in PHP (on App Engine or not), is to use the [Google Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/).